# Android -- how does one filter console spam from Eclipse LogCat?

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

The default Eclipse LogCat window contains a lot of console spam from the VM, etc. How does one remove these messages? It seems that the only filters now are to filter *for* an expression, not *filter out* spam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is `LogCat` by definition, from [Developer Page - LogCat](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html):

```
logcat

The Android logging system provides a mechanism for collecting and viewing system debug 
output. Logs from various applications and portions of the system are collected in a 
series of circular buffers, which then can be viewed and filtered by the logcat command. 
You can use logcat from an ADB shell to view the log messages.
```

well, you take what you need by take a filtering by tag, by process id, by string or by an expression.
Anyway, if you're not much familiar with `Logcat`, please try this guide first - [Learn how to control Logcat output](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html#outputFormat)

Comment: The tag/priority system on that page you linked is great, thanks! I'm now using `adb logcat MyAppTag:V '*:W'`, which shows everything from my app, and warnings from anything else.

Answer (score 7):

Also if you want to filter log messages that you are not interested in then the silent option (S) for logcat's "filter_spec" can be used.

For example if you want to filter the Dalvik VM's log messsages like

> D/dalvikvm(28039): GC_CONCURRENT freed 473K, 7% free 9503K/10180K, paused 2ms+3ms, total 22ms

then you may use

```
adb logcat dalvikvm:S
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the command line instead.

```
appname=YOUR_APP_NAME_OR_LOG_TAG
adb logcat | awk '/'$appname'/{gsub(/'$appname'/, "\x1b[95m'$appname'\x1b[0m"); print; next}; /(dalvikvm|com.google.android.apps|PhoneStatusBar|DeviceConfig)/{next}; {print}'
```

This will highlight your application's name, remove messages containing typically spammy messages, and print anything it doesn't know about.